# Drawing fluid pathlines, streaklines, streamlines using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to do a sketch of fluid pathlines, streaklines, and streamlines using TikZ.  The code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [fill=blue!25] (0.0, 0.0) -- (0.0, 2.0) -- (6.0, 2.0) -- (6.0, 1.0) to[out=180, in=0] (0.0, 0.0);
  \filldraw [semithick, fill=gray!50] (0.0, 2.0) rectangle (6.0, 2.1);
  \filldraw [semithick, fill=gray!50] (0.0, -0.1) -- (0.0, 0.0) to[out=0, in=180] (6.0, 1.0) -- (6.0, 0.9) to[out=180, in=0] (0.0, -0.1);
  %
  \draw [thick] (0.25, 0.25) to[out=0, in=180] node [pos=0.1, above] {$t_{1}$} node [pos=0.5, above] {$t_{2}$} node [pos=0.9, above] {$t_{3}$} (5.75, 1.125);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates the following image:

[image]

I would like there to be closed circles on the black line at the locations under the labels $t_{1}$, $t_{2}$, and $t_{3}$.  Can someone suggest how to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: I would go with [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby), definitely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also just add extra nodes as you go, one for the filled circles, and one for the label:

[image]

### Notes:

- Also see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [fill=blue!25] (0.0, 0.0) -- (0.0, 2.0) -- (6.0, 2.0) -- (6.0, 1.0) to[out=180, in=0] (0.0, 0.0);
  \filldraw [semithick, fill=gray!50] (0.0, 2.0) rectangle (6.0, 2.1);
  \filldraw [semithick, fill=gray!50] (0.0, -0.1) -- (0.0, 0.0) to[out=0, in=180] (6.0, 1.0) -- (6.0, 0.9) to[out=180, in=0] (0.0, -0.1);
  %
  \draw [thick] (0.25, 0.25) to[out=0, in=180] 
              node [pos=0.1, circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt] {}
              node [pos=0.1, above] {$t_{1}$} 
              node [pos=0.5, circle, fill=blue, inner sep=2pt] {}
              node [pos=0.5, above] {$t_{2}$} 
              node [pos=0.9, circle, fill=orange, inner sep=2pt] {}
              node [pos=0.9, above] {$t_{3}$} (5.75, 1.125);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I did not realize that I could create two nodes in the same physical location, such as you showed.  This worked well.

Comment: @Josh: Glad it worked for you. Please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Specify coordinates inline rather than nodes. Then you can build up any constructs you require later on, like so:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [fill=blue!25] (0.0, 0.0) -- (0.0, 2.0) -- (6.0, 2.0) -- (6.0, 1.0) to[out=180, in=0] (0.0, 0.0);
  \filldraw [semithick, fill=gray!50] (0.0, 2.0) rectangle (6.0, 2.1);
  \filldraw [semithick, fill=gray!50] (0.0, -0.1) -- (0.0, 0.0) 
    to[out=0, in=180] (6.0, 1.0) -- (6.0, 0.9) to[out=180, in=0] (0.0, -0.1);
  %
  \draw [thick] (0.25, 0.25) to[out=0, in=180] coordinate[pos=0.1] (1) 
    coordinate[pos=0.5] (2)  coordinate[pos=0.9] (3) (5.75, 1.125);
  \foreach \coord in {1,2,3}{%
    \node[above] at (\coord) {$t_{\coord}$};
    \fill (\coord) circle (2pt);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output is:
[image]